# Math.Sin, Math.Cos and Math.Tan precision and way to display them correctly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, math

I'm coding a calculator in C#.

`textBoxResult` is a text box where I display the number

`recount` is the function which takes the angle in degrees and returns in radians

I take the angle from `texBoxInput`

```
public double recount(int number)
{
    double wyjscie = 0.0;
    double Number = number;
    wyjscie = Number * (Math.PI / 180);
    return wyjscie;
}

//function which is called out when user presses the button:
textBoxResult.Text = Math.Round(Math.Tan(recount(Convert.ToInt32(texBoxInput.Text))),2).ToString();
```

As you can see I was trying to round this number when using `Math.Tan`, but still `Math.Tan` gives me that tan from 90 degrees is 1,63317787283838E+16 .

I have been trying to find the answer but failed. I can't figure it out how to display correct result.

Comment: Define "correct result".

Comment: As the correct result i mean 0.00

Comment: Please show the actual code that you are using. `out` is a reserved word and can not be used as a variable name (without the @ specifier). The function that you have showed doesn't compile, and if it did, it wouldn't return the calculated value.

Comment: I think its a typo  `ToString())`

Comment: Isn't tan of 90 degress +/- infinity?

Comment: Sorry for that (I changed the names of some variables just to make everything clear). It is changed.

Comment: @Rawling It is +Inf :) So, in fact, it is 'close' to correct result. I don't know if it's going to return `true` from `double.IsInfinity` but it's worth checking.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I just havent thought about it. Still have to revise some math.

Comment: It doesn't return true form double.IsInfinity.

Comment: @MarcinMajewski That was just a suggestion, I don't know how `IsInfinity` works inside. :) Still, [Wolfram Alpha does not lie](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Tan%28PI%2F2%29).

Comment: I don't know either, just checked and shared the result :) Thank you once again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, it looks like this is expected behavior from `Math.Tan`.  I don't know other languages very well, so I'm not sure if this is normal for floating point Math or specific to the C# implementation. (NOTE: Afterwards, I found that Google's online calculator returns the same suggesting it expected behavior for floating point trig functions, probably related to the fact that *pi* is irrational and the limitations of the double precision data type)

However, working backwards from this result I am seeing that `Math.Atan(// your result);` and `Math.Atan(double.PositiveInfinity)` both return 90 degrees, suggesting this is expected?

Here's my test:

```
var deg = 90.0;
var rads = deg * (Math.PI / 180);
var result = Math.Tan(rads);

if (Double.IsInfinity(result))
    Console.WriteLine("Tan of 90 degrees is Infinity");
else if (Double.IsNaN(result))
    Console.WriteLine("Tan of 90 degrees is Undefined");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Tan of 90 degrees is {0}", result);

Console.WriteLine("Arc Tan of {0} is {1} degrees", double.PositiveInfinity, Math.Atan(double.PositiveInfinity) * 180 / Math.PI);
Console.WriteLine("Arc Tan of {0} is {1} degrees", result, Math.Atan(result) * 180 / Math.PI);
```

Which gives the output of:

```
Tan of 90 degrees is 1.63317787283838E+16
Arc Tan of Infinity is 90 degrees
Arc Tan of 1.63317787283838E+16 is 90 degrees
```

So my guess is unless someone can come in and provide a workaround, you might have to program around this as an edge case to get the correct result.

The "correct result" for any of the trig functions will be limited to the precision of `double`, which is 15 significant figures, so if you need more than that, you will need to find a library that supports more precise mathematics.

Since `Math.Tan(Math.PI/2)` seems to provide an undesirable response you could do something like this:

```
public double ComputeTangent(double angleRads)
{
    if (angleRads == Math.PI/2)
        return double.PositiveInfinity
    if (angleRads == - Math.PI/2)
        return double.NegativeInfinity

    return Math.Tan(angleRads);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting, it made me sure that it is correct behaviour of program.

Comment: @MarcinMajewski I added a possible workaround for the `Math.Tan()` issue for 90 degrees (and -90 degrees too)

Answer (score 1):

`Round` is doing [exactly what it says on the tin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx):

> The maximum total number of integral and fractional digits that can be
>   returned is 15. If the rounded value contains more than 15 digits, the
>   15 most significant digits are returned. If the rounded value contains
>   15 or fewer digits, the integral digits and as many fractional digits
>   as the digits parameter specifies are returned.

`1.63317787283838E+16` are the 15 most significant digits, and there is no fractional part.

If you want to display this as `1,63E+016` you can use:

`number.ToString('E2', CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"))`

(Or any other locale that uses `,` as the decimal separator )

See: [The Exponential ("E") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#EFormatString)

Answer (score 1):

```
 using System;

namespace Lab_Ex_12
{
    class SimpleCalculator
    {
        double num1, num2;
        public void read()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n Enter any two numbers:");
            Console.Write("\n Number1 : ");
            num1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("\n Number2 : ");
            num2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        public void add()
        {
            double sum = num1 + num2;
            Console.WriteLine("\n Result : ({0}) + ({1}) = {2}", num1, num2, sum);
        }
        public void subtract()
        {
            double diff = num1 - num2;
            Console.WriteLine("\n Result : ({0}) - ({1}) = {2}", num1, num2, diff);
        }
        public void multiply()
        {
            double prod = num1 * num2;
            Console.WriteLine("\n Result : ({0}) X ({1}) = {2}", num1, num2, prod);
        }
        public void divide()
        {
            double qt = num1 / num2;
            Console.WriteLine("\n Result : ({0}) / ({1}) = {2}", num1, num2, qt);
        }
    }
    class ArithmeticOperations
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            SimpleCalculator SC = new SimpleCalculator();
            int ch, i=1;
            while(i==1)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\n *************************");
                Console.WriteLine("\n   ZAHID SIMPLE CALCULATOR.");
                Console.WriteLine("\n *************************");
                Console.WriteLine("\n 1-----> ADDITION");
                Console.WriteLine("\n 2-----> SUBTRACTION");
                Console.WriteLine("\n 3-----> MULTIPLICATION");
                Console.WriteLine("\n 4-----> DIVISION");
                Console.WriteLine("\n 5-----> EXIT");
                Console.WriteLine("\n *************************");
                Console.Write("\n\n Enter your choice: ");
                ch = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (ch)
                {
                    case 1: SC.read();
                            SC.add();
                            break;
                    case 2: SC.read();
                            SC.subtract();
                            break;
                    case 3: SC.read();
                            SC.multiply();
                            break;
                    case 4: SC.read();
                            SC.divide();
                            break;
                    case 5: Environment.Exit(-1);
                            break;
                    default: Console.WriteLine(" Sorry !!! Wrong  choice.");
                            break;
                }
                Console.Write("\n Press ENTER to Continue. ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n Cannot continue... Bye");
        }
    }
}
```