# Mathf.Tan giving strange results

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have one problem in finding tan angle in my Unity3d game.

The code is as follows

```
b = Mathf.Deg2Rad * (90.0f - angle);
float tan = Mathf.Tan (b);
Debug.Log ("Value of b :  " + b + "  Tan of b  :  " + tan);
```

Here the value **angle is 0.**

The problem with me is when I calculate using calculator I will get the **result of b as 1.570796327** which is correct and **value of tan is 0.027422438** when my calculator is in degree mode and **INFINITY ** in radians mode

The debug log results are as follows

**Value of b :  1.570796  Tan of b  :  -2.287733E+07**

What is the problem? Please excuse if I am wrong.

Comment: The problem probably arises from inaccuracies in the Math.Tan method, you can have a look at previous answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108651/math-sin-math-cos-and-math-tan-precision-and-way-to-display-them-correctly

Answer (score 2):

Due to inaccuracies in the floating point numbers, the tangent was calculated for an angle slightly over `π/2` rad (90 deg), resulting in your large negative answer.

If you want to better account for this case, you should check if `b` is close enough to `pi/2`: if it is, then the tangent is undefined. E.g.

```
// if necessary, also account for 3pi/2 (270 deg)
if (Math.Abs(b - Math.PI / 2) < 0.00001)
    // undefined or infinite
else
    // finite, calculate tangent like normal
```